# Clearing cache and cookies freezes Firefox on Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, firefox

Every time I try to clear my cache or cookies, the system freezes and crashes. The spinning wheel continues and I have to force quit/reboot.

How can I clear my cache & cookies without Firefox freezing?

<sup>MacBook Pro, OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall Firefox by deleting it from `/Applications` and copying it from a fresh download.

If that does not help (which is likely), you may have a corrupt Firefox profile. To fix it:

1. Use the [Firefox Profile Manager](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager#Mac_OS_X), create a new profile and see if it works without crashing.
2. If it does, then [transfer data to the new profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox#Firefox_4_and_above) from the old one.